# Observables created at time interval

Tags: scala, observable, rx-scala

I was looking at the RxScala observables which are created at a given time interval:

```
val periodic: Observable[Long] = Observable.interval(100 millis)

periodic.foreach(x => println(x))
```

If I put this in a worksheet, I get this result:

```
periodic: rx.lang.scala.Observable[Long] = rx.lang.scala.JavaConversions$$anon$2@2cce3493

res0: Unit = ()
```

This leaves me confused: What do the elements of `periodic` actually contain?

Do they contain some index?
Do they contain the time interval at which they were created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read here http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html produced elements are `Long` values incrementing from `0`.

As for your code and results:

Here, you create the observable, and get `Observable[Long]` assigned to `periodic`. Everything as expected.

```
scala> val periodic: Observable[Long] = Observable.interval(100 millis)
periodic: rx.lang.scala.Observable[Long] = rx.lang.scala.JavaConversions$$anon$2@2cce3493
```

Here, you register a callback, i.e. what happens when value is emmited. The return type of `foreach` method is `Unit` as it doesn't have a reasonable value and happens just for the side effect of registering callbacks.

```
periodic.foreach(x => println(x))
res0: Unit = ()
```

You don't see actual values because execution stops. Try to insert `Thread.sleep`.

```
val periodic: Observable[Long] = Observable.interval(100.millis)
periodic.foreach(x => println(x))
Thread.sleep(1000)
```

Gives output similar to

```
periodic: rx.lang.scala.Observable[Long] = rx.lang.scala.JavaConversions$$anon$2@207cb62f

res0: Unit = ()

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
res1: Unit = ()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that interval is asynchronous, so you´re not waiting for the result.

Another way to wait for the result is use TestSubscriber

```
def interval(): Unit = {
addHeader("Interval observable")
Observable.interval(createDuration(100))
  .map(n => "New item emitted:" + n)
  .doOnNext(s => print("\n" + s))
  .subscribe();
new TestSubscriber[Subscription].awaitTerminalEvent(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
 }
```

You can see more examples here https://github.com/politrons/reactiveScala